# How to pack angular library for new version tgz?

Tags: angular, npm

I have angular library project that version is 1.0.0 in package.json file. So I am running `npm pack` command. It generates a tgz file `my-lib-1.0.0.tgz`. And I do some changes in library and change version number of package.json to 1.0.1, and running `npm pack` again. But the generated tgs file does not change  `my-lib-1.0.0.tgz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your library with prod parameter and run `npm pack`. If you do not buil, old files are packaging in dist folder.